# xerox workcentre 5855 scan a document and save it for reprint

Tags: printing, copy, scanning, xerox

How can I scan a document using **Xerox WorkCentre 5855** and save it to the device local storage for reprinting later?

i find "*save jobs for reprint*" in internet but can't find this button in my device and i'm not sure this is what i'm looking for.

Comment: Hi and welcome here. Maybe your question is out of the scope of SO. Here, you have to submit code you have written, with which you encounter a technical issue.